# Custom Gradle exec tasks won't run in parallel

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

My goal is that I can run `./gradlew deployStaging`, and it executes `buildDockerStatic`, and `buildDockerBackend` in parallel, and after both tasks have finished, the `deployStaging` will run. With the code below, the tasks run serially. I've tried a few things, but `buildDockerStatic`, and `buildDockerBackend` always run serially.

```
tasks.register("buildDockerStatic", BuildDockerStatic) {
    workingDir rootDir
}

tasks.register("buildDockerBackend", BuildDockerBackend) {
    workingDir rootDir
}

//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
task deployStaging() {
    dependsOn tasks.buildDockerStatic
    dependsOn tasks.buildDockerBackend

    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir rootDir
            commandLine 'sh', './scripts/build_deploy_staging.sh'
        }
    }
}

class BuildDockerStatic extends AbstractExecTask<BuildDockerStatic> {
    BuildDockerStatic() {
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        super(BuildDockerStatic)

        commandLine 'sh', './scripts/build_static.sh'
    }
}

class BuildDockerBackend extends AbstractExecTask<BuildDockerBackend> {
    BuildDockerBackend() {
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        super(BuildDockerBackend)

        commandLine 'sh', './scripts/build_backend.sh'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to be run in parallel, the build tasks need to be placed in sub-projects.

They should contain `doLast`; otherwise they will be executed when calling eg. `gradle clean`. And probably, a definition using the plain `task {..}` will be enough.

---

**Parallel:** from the docs at [Gradle:parallel execution](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_execution)

> By using the --parallel switch, you can force Gradle to execute tasks in parallel as long as those tasks are in different projects.

---

See a modified example below; it will run two sub-tasks (to sleep and log), in parallel.

It can be run with `gradle clean deployStaging --parallel`

**Multi project structure**

```
build-backend
  +--build.gradle
build-static
  +--build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

`build-backend/build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'base'
task buildDockerBackend {
  doLast{
    exec {
      println 'BuildDockerBackend: started at ' + new java.util.Date()
      workingDir rootDir
      sleep 4000
      //commandLine 'sh', './scripts/build_backend.sh'
      commandLine 'echo', 'task: build-backend'
      println 'BuildDockerBackend: done at    ' + new java.util.Date()
    }
  }
}
```

`build-static/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'base'
task buildDockerStatic {
  doLast{
    exec {
      println 'BuildDockerStatic: started at ' + new java.util.Date()
      workingDir rootDir
      sleep 8000
      //commandLine 'sh', './scripts/build_static.sh'
      commandLine 'echo', 'task: build-static'
      println 'BuildDockerStatic: done at    ' + new java.util.Date()
    }
  }
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'base'
task deployStaging {
  doLast {
    exec {
      workingDir rootDir
      //commandLine 'sh', './scripts/build_deploy_staging.sh'
      commandLine 'echo', 'task: deploy-staging'
    }
  }
}
deployStaging.dependsOn ':build-static:buildDockerStatic'
deployStaging.dependsOn ':build-backend:buildDockerBackend'
```

`settings.gradle`

```
include 'build-static'
include 'build-backend'
```